# Moto sns client can't call create_topic AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'create_topic'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, moto

I'm trying to follow the docs to do this:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN"] = "testing"
    os.environ["AWS_SESSION_TOKEN"] = "testing"


@pytest.fixture()
def sts(aws_credentials):
    with mock_sts():
        yield boto3.client("sts", region_name="us-east-1")


@pytest.fixture
def sns(aws_credentials):
    with mock_sns():
        yield boto3.resource("sns", region_name="us-east-1")


def test_publish(sns):
    resp = sns.create_topic(Name="sdfsdfsdfsd")
```

I get error:

```
    def test_publish(sns):
>       topic_arn = sns.create_topic(Name="sdfsdfsdfsd")
E       AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'create_topic'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm not 100% sure why but adding the sts decorator seems to have fixed this:

```
@mock_sts
def test_publish(sns):
    resp = sns.create_topic(Name="sdfsdfsdfsd")
```

I figured that out from this article but I'm still unclear on how it works: https://www.serverlessops.io/blog/aws-lambda-serverless-development-workflow-part2-testing-debugging

Is this because boto needs to use sts so I need to mock that out too? I use a credentials file with profiles to access AWS from laptop

### Edit

You also, MUST use yield to return the client. Using return here gave me an sts error. I'd like to understand this better as well. I assume I need to use yield because it's a generator?

```
@pytest.fixture
def sns(aws_credentials):
    with mock_sns():
        # using return here causes below error
        return boto3.resource("sns", region_name="us-east-1")
```

Error when not using yield:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the CreateTopic operation: The security token included in the request is invalid